# Perform if-check for each element with certain class name in the DOM using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working on an asp.net mvc 3 application view. I'm creating forms dynamically based on data taken from the database. Some of the text boxes are editable so they need validation before sending them back for save (of course there will be back end validation too) but because of the dynamic nature of the forms I don't know which text boxes should be validated - this information also comes form the database, so I've created three classes for the three type of validation I may need to perform and with the help of the users here I managed to write this :

```
$('#submitDocument').click(function (e) {
            if ($(".checkString16 input[type='text']:first").val().length > 16) {
                alert("16 symbols max");
                e.preventDefault();
            } else if (!mathFunctions.isInt($(".checkULong input[type='text']:first").val())) {
                alert("Integer");
                e.preventDefault();
            } else if (!mathFunctions.isFloat($(".checkFloat input[type='text']:first").val())) {
                alert("Float");
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    });
```

and my `mathFunctions` object :

```
mathFunctions = {
            isInt: function (value) {
                return value % 1 == 0;
            },

            isFloat: function (value) {
                return ($.isNumeric(value) && value % 1 != 0);
            }
        };
```

However. The problem here is that it checks only the first hit on an element from a certain class (even though if I remove the `:first` from `input[type='text']:first`. So as result if I have three text boxes of class `checkFloat` it will always alert if the first text box don't pass the check, but if the first text box have a correct data and the others are incorrect the submit is still processed and there is no alert message from which I think that it only check the first element with this class name and then stops. I tried to do something with the `each()` function :

```
else if ($(".checkFloat input[type='text']:first")).each(function(){!mathFunctions.isFloat(val())})) {
                alert("Float!");
            }
```

But most important - it's not working, and it seem rather complicated so I guess I'm trying to use it in a wrong way.

So the most important question - how can I perform check for all elements form a certain class and even though I think that this can be accomplished with `each()` maybe there's other ways, I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same val in the each loop, you have to tell the each loop to take the current's element val and I'd rather wont do it as a if condition, although its possible.

```
$('#submitDocument').click(function (e) {
        if ($(".checkString16 input[type='text']:first").val().length > 16) {
            alert("16 symbols max");
            e.preventDefault();
        } else if (!mathFunctions.isInt($(".checkULong input[type='text']:first").val())) {
            alert("Integer");
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            var test = false;
            $(".checkFloat input[type='text']").each(function() {
                if (!mathFunctions.isFloat($(this).val())) test = true;
            });

            if (test) {
                alert("Float");
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. I have very basic knowledge about JS/jQuery what do you think is a better approach here?